# how to know continuous typing in uisearchbar and when typing stopped in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I want to execute a method when user stop typing without resign the keyboard and when user typing the method will not be execute.

Comment: Can you explain that better? You want the method to be called when the user stops typing for a time or when he deselects the textField?

Comment: I want execute a method when the user stops typing for a time not deselect it.

Comment: You can't stop a method immediately. If you want to do something according to the words user typed, you'd better do it in another thread and notify the result to main thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with or without `NSTimer`.

#### 1.Without `NSTimer`:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(request) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(request) withObject:nil afterDelay:YOUR_DESIRED_PAUSE_TIME];
 }
```

#### 2.Using `NSTimer`:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (theTimer) 
    {
        if ([theTimer isValid]) 
        { 
            [theTimer invalidate]; 
        }
        theTimer = nil;
    }
    theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:YOUR_DESIRED_PAUSE_TIME target:self selector:@selector(userPaused:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't any direct way to do this, so you'll have to workaround it a bit.

There is a delegate method that you can listen to when the user types.
I would use this, and set a timer as a property, activated there (3 seconds for example). If the user types again, I would restart the timer.
That way, the timer will only fire if the user stops typing for 3 seconds.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(self.timer)
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }       
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3 target:self selector: @selector(timerFired:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
}
```

This should do what you want! Don't forget to invalidate the timer when the user deselects the search bar.